# Issue with Overlay in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am training to make a responsive site with bootstrap. So far so good, even if I imagine that my code is not super clean. The concern that has been bothering me for a few hours is that I can't overlay the image.

Anyway, I can't manage to make this overlay correspond to the size of the image and not the size of the `<div>` in which this overlay is located.

I simplified my case to make it easier to settle.

So I have an overflowing frame concern: the background (in blue at the bottom on the image below) is the size of a `<div>` and `<row>` but not the size of the image. The image itself automatically has 25px of padding on top, 15px on right and the same on left.

My background on the other hand, does not have these padding at all and it is needless to say that putting a padding on my div does not change anything. I just can't seem to make this div the right size. Or rather a size that corresponds to that of my image whose padding seems inherent to the functioning of bootstrap ...

Here what it looks like visually with the Firefox console which shows the padding and the size of the div.

[What I have in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lISM.png)

The code bellow :

http://jsfiddle.net/o9vjn3bm/

```css
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 540px;/*Pour les très petits écrans.*/
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 720px; /*Pour les petits écrans*/
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 1200px;/*Pour les écrans moyens*/
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1920px) {
  .container-fluid {
    width: 1900px;/*Pour les grands écrans*/
  }
}
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
/*MENUS DU HAUT*/
nav > div > div[class*="menu-haut"] {
  background-color: black;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > div > div > a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav > div > div > a:hover {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dessins {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
.dessins:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1) url("images/separateur.png") no-repeat bottom;
}

.videos {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}

.videos:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1) url("images/separateur.png") no-repeat bottom;
}
.cv {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
.cv:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,1) url("images/separateur.png") no-repeat bottom;
}

/*MENUS DU BAS*/
nav > div > div[class*="menu-dessins"] {
    border-top : 2px solid white;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nb {
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    border-right : 1px solid white;
}

.couleurs {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    border-left : 1px solid white;
}
.col-xl-4
 {
   padding-left: 15px;
 }

/*SECTION DESSINS*/

.fit-image{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.overlay {

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: blue;
  height: 15%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.ctr {
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  text-align: center;
}

.content:hover{
  opacity : 1;
}

.reve {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right : 10px;
  max-width: 100%;

}
.amour {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.charogne {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left : 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" lang="fr"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Batche - Dessins</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_batche_1_dessins.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

<body>
 <header> <!--Je place mon menu dans le header-->
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
   
    <nav class="col-12 menus .bg-dark"> <!-- Menus -->
     
     <div class="nav">
    
     <div class="menu-haut col-4 nav-item dessins">
     
     <a class="nav-link active" href="site_batche_dessins.html">Dessins</a>
     </div>
  
     <div class="menu-haut col-4 nav-item videos">
     <a class="nav-link active" href="site_batche_videos.html">Vidéos</a>
     </div>
  
     <div class="menu-haut col-4 nav-item cv">
     <a class="nav-link" href="site_batche_cv.html">Cv</a>
     </div>

     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>

 <section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <nav class="col-12">
    
     <div class="nav">
    
     <div class="menu-dessins col-6 nav-item nb">
     <a class="nav-link active" href="#noir_blanc">Noir & Blanc</a>
     </div>
  
     <div class="menu-dessins col-6 nav-item couleurs">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#couleurs">Couleur</a>
     </div>
     
     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </div>  
 </section>

 <section id="Le_reve">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">

    <div class=" wrapper reve col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
     <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.calliaweb.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2F600x600.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="reve" class="img-fluid fit-image">

     <div class="overlay ctr"></div>

    </div>    
    
    

    <div class="wrapper amour col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
     <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.calliaweb.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2F600x600.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="amour" class="img-fluid fit-image">

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper charogne col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
     <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.calliaweb.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F10%2F600x600.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt="charogne" class="img-fluid fit-image">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>


 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me ? I'm sure there is a solution but my level is too low to find it by myself, even after hours !

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Using the JSFiddle as an example, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi I explained my problem. I used JSFiddle because maybe it's more simple for people to see what's the problem !

A background has the size of a '<div>' not of the picture.

Comment: Oh... I see. Let's see what's going on.

Comment: Okay cool thank you !  :)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Please, can you explain me why this happened ? I never defined that there should be a 15px **padding**. I did not know 'calc' now it is! Thank you again !

Comment: Edited my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.overlay` parent class:

`wrapper reve col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12` has a `padding: 15px`.

So the `width: 100%` will respect that.

I'd use `width: calc(100% - 30px);` (30px for each 15px side)

**EDIT:** The 15px padding comes from `.col-*` Bootstrap classes. You can check the "Computed" tab on your browser for the source code.
Line 628:

```
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col,
.col-auto, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm,
.col-sm-auto, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md,
.col-md-auto, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg,
.col-lg-auto, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl,
.col-xl-auto {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Just a FYI, `calc` _can_ be expensive, don't go wild with it! Reading the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) is very helpful!